# Lists in jquery UI tabs

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I am having trouble rendering lists within a tab.
ex.

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
      <p>Tab 1</p>
        <div id="validate">
            <ul>
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Tab 2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
      <p> Tab 3 </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

In above example The nested list is not rendered as a list. Check here http://jsfiddle.net/3YyHz/

This is causing problem because validation summary in MVC is returned as a list but the display gets all screwed up because its on a tab.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the missing styling? I think you just have a css issue where Jquery UI list style is overriding the nested list. I updated your fiddle with some inline css for demonstration.